# Create random value in same pattern as existing id field

Tags: sql, db2

The following query:

```
SELECT id, var1, var2, var3 FROM my_table
```

returns this result:

```
+----------+------+------+------+
| id       | var1 | var2 | var3 |
+----------+------+------+------+
| 43245324 | A    | 1    | 2    |
+----------+------+------+------+
| 43245324 | B    | 2    | 3    |
+----------+------+------+------+
| 11112233 | A    | 2    | 2    |
+----------+------+------+------+
| 11112233 | A    | 2    | 2    |
+----------+------+------+------+
| 11112233 | C    | 3    | 3    |
+----------+------+------+------+
| 23312222 | H    | 5    | 1    |
+----------+------+------+------+
| 23312222 | Q    | 3    | 3    |
+----------+------+------+------+
```

What I need is for a new id field that can be random but needs to be consistent with the existing id. For example every instance of 43245324 needs to have the same corresponding newID. How would I adjust my query to return a result with something like:

```
+----------+-------+------+------+------+
| id       | newid | var1 | var2 | var3 |
+----------+-------+------+------+------+
| 43245324 | 1     | A    | 1    | 2    |
+----------+-------+------+------+------+
| 43245324 | 1     | B    | 2    | 3    |
+----------+-------+------+------+------+
| 11112233 | 2     | A    | 2    | 2    |
+----------+-------+------+------+------+
| 11112233 | 2     | A    | 2    | 2    |
+----------+-------+------+------+------+
| 11112233 | 2     | C    | 3    | 3    |
+----------+-------+------+------+------+
| 23312222 | 3     | H    | 5    | 1    |
+----------+-------+------+------+------+
| 23312222 | 3     | Q    | 3    | 3    |
+----------+-------+------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by id) as newid
from mytable t;
```

This will assign a value starting at `1` with no gaps based on the ordering of `id`.

By the way, if you wanted a "random" value, you could use `rand()` with a seed:

```
select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by rand(id), id) as newid
from mytable t;
```